# Indian Religions/Castes List?

Tags: data-request, demographics, india, religion

I am developing a matrimony web application, for this a list of Indian religions and their belonging castes is required.

Does anyone know of a data set containing the Indian castes and/or religions organized by geographic region?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Wikipedia [list of Indian Religions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_religions).

The caste system has been banned in India. If you would like a basic dataset, you [can look to this answer.](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/indian-caste-dataset?rq=1)